# Как использовать Idling resources в espresso без модификации продукторого кода?

Tags: java, android, espresso

Пишу автотесты c использованием Espresso и сотлкнулся с проблемой, что часто необходимо ожидать появления какого-то объекта на экране. Использовать `thread.sleep` не очень помогает, потому что время ожидания может быть разным и тесты становятся слишком долгими. Почитал про `idling resources` вроде то что надо. Но проблема в том что мне нельзя модифицировать продакшн код, поэтому повсеместные примеры с `CountingIdlingResources` не подходят мне. Есть вроде как какие-то `DataBindingIdlingResources`, но я не понимаю как их использовать. Есть здесь знатоки Espresso которые растолковать понятно могут?